# Screen resolution

Tags: hdmi

If I start the pi withe the display unplugged and then plug it in later, the screen resolution is too low. I can only solve this by restarting the machine. Is there a way to solve this without restarting the machine ?

Comment: Why do you plug in your display after the pi has booted? I think the simplest way to fix this is just plug the cable in before the pi boots.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, it's only by hardcoding a specific resolution into `/boot/config.txt`, e.g.:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
```

Should guarantee you HD resolution (1080p @60 Hz) if you plug in a cable after power up, and in my experience will work with most modern TVs and monitors.  For a complete list of the possible options [see here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi_group).

Answer (score 1):

Set resolution into /boot/config.txt directory..

> Force the monitor to HDMI mode so that sound will be sent over HDMI cable

```
hdmi_drive=2
```

> Set monitor mode to DMT

```
hdmi_group=2
```

> Set monitor resolution to 1024x768 XGA 60Hz (HDMI_DMT_XGA_60)

```
hdmi_mode=16
```

> Make display smaller to stop text spilling off the screen

```
overscan_left=20
overscan_right=12
overscan_top=10
overscan_bottom=10
```